# How to get the (n) largest values from a pandas data frame? And label them as '1' else '0'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

date = pd.date_range('10/01/2018', periods=5, freq='D')

close = pd.DataFrame({
    'ABC': [1, 5, 3, 6, 2],
    'EFG': [12, 51, 43, 56, 22],
    'XYZ': [35, 36, 36, 36, 37],
}, [date])
```

And I want to get the full data frame with '1' for the largest value in each row and '0' for the other two columns.

If I want to have two largest values for each row, it should label '1' for those largest values and '0' for others and etc.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, you could go with checking if the [`pd.DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) for each row is above your threshold.

```
# Number of largest values you want to mark
n = 1

# Solution
out = df.rank(axis=1, method="first", ascending=False).le(n).astype(int)
```

out:

```
            ABC  EFG  XYZ
2018-10-01    0    0    1
2018-10-02    0    1    0
2018-10-03    0    1    0
2018-10-04    0    1    0
2018-10-05    0    0    1
```

Also interesting is [`pd.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), but it doesn't help so much with marking the positions of the largest values in the original dataframe.

If you need speed, then I recommend dropping down to numpy and doing some [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) trickery.

Comment: Glad it worked! I made the code a little cleaner (I think) with `ascending=False` :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try

```
close.eq(close.max(1), axis=0)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response! This worked great for finding one largest value. However, I'm unable to get the two largest values if I change the code to `close.eq(close.where(close != 0).max(2), axis=0)`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?